# Display data in categorywise

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I had one list named category. It contains the following data.

```
Name  -                  Id 
----------------------------
Mobile  -                 0
Cellphones -             21
Mobile Accessories -     22
Camera -                  0
Camcorder -              55
Camera Accessories       60
SLRs                     61
Photo Printers           63
Computers                0
Laptops                  65
Memory Cards             67
Monitors                 69
RAM                      70
Computer Accessories     71
```

And i want to display above data as following way using Ul and Li tag :

**Mobile**

-Cellphones

-Mobile Accessories

**Camera**

-Camcorder

-Camera Accessories

-SLRs

-Photo Printers

**Computers**

-Laptops

-Memory Cards

-Monitors

-RAM

-Computer Accessories

That is id=0 means parent category and id=non-zero means subcategory

Help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverFlow. But may you be more specific !.

Answer (score 0):

```
Namespace Test

Public Class Class1

    Dim Categories As List(Of Category) = New List(Of Category) _
                                          From {New Category With {
                                                .ID = 0, .Name = "Mobile",
                                                .Items = New List(Of CategoryItem) _
                                                    From {New CategoryItem With {.ID = 1, .Name = "Cellphones"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 2, .Name = "Mobile Accessories"}
                                                         }
                                                },
                                                New Category With {
                                                .ID = 1, .Name = "Camera",
                                                .Items = New List(Of CategoryItem) _
                                                    From {New CategoryItem With {.ID = 1, .Name = "Camcorder"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 2, .Name = "Camera Accessories"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 3, .Name = "SLRs"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 4, .Name = "Photo Printers"}
                                                         }
                                                },
                                                New Category With {
                                                .ID = 2, .Name = "Computers",
                                                .Items = New List(Of CategoryItem) _
                                                    From {New CategoryItem With {.ID = 1, .Name = "Laptops"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 2, .Name = "Memory Cards"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 3, .Name = "Monitors"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 4, .Name = "RAM"},
                                                          New CategoryItem With {.ID = 5, .Name = "Computer Accessories"}
                                                         }
                                                }
                                                }

    Public Sub New()
     Dim ul As String =  SetCategories()
    End Sub

    Private Function SetCategories() As String
        Dim ulCategories As XElement = <ul class="float-left"></ul>

        For Each cat As Category In Categories
            Dim currentCategory As Category = cat
            Dim liCategory As XElement = <li><%= currentCategory.Name %></li>
            Dim ulCategoryItems As XElement = <ul></ul>
            For Each item As CategoryItem In currentCategory.Items
                Dim currentItem As CategoryItem = item
                Dim liItem As XElement = <li><%= currentItem.Name %></li>
                ulCategoryItems.Add(liItem)
            Next item
            liCategory.Add(ulCategoryItems)
            ulCategories.Add(liCategory)
        Next cat

        Return ulCategories.ToString()

    End Function

End Class

Public Class Category

    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Items As List(Of CategoryItem)

End Class

Public Class CategoryItem
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: In addition to your code segment you should also briefly explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here, put this in your view:

```
<ul>
    <li>Mobile
      <ul>
          <li>Cellphones</li>
          <li>Mobile Accessories</li>
      </ul>
    </li>    
    <li>Camera
      <ul>
          <li>Camcorder</li>
          <li>Camera Accessories</li>
          <li>SLRs</li>
          <li>Photo Printers</li>
      </ul>
    </li>    
    <li>Computers
      <ul>
          <li>Laptops</li>
          <li>Memory Cards</li>
          <li>Monitors</li>
          <li>RAM</li>
          <li>Computer Accessories</li>
      </ul>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

---

While that is what you are asking for, I think you are wanting something a little more.

Because there is nothing specific in your question or any attempt in your part, several assumptions where made in the following solution.

Class:

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Category> Subcateogries { get; set; }

  public Category()
  {
    Subcateogries = new List<Category>();
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //The Data
  var categories = new List<Category>
  {
    new Category { Id = 0, Name = "Mobile" },
    new Category { Id = 21, Name = "Cellphones" },
    new Category { Id = 22, Name = "Mobile Accessories" },
    new Category { Id = 0, Name = "Camera" },
    new Category { Id = 55, Name = "Camcorder" },
    new Category { Id = 60, Name = "Camera Accessories" },
    new Category { Id = 61, Name = "SLRs" },
    new Category { Id = 63, Name = "Photo Printers" },
    new Category { Id = 0, Name = "Computers" },
    new Category { Id = 65, Name = "Laptops" },
    new Category { Id = 67, Name = "Memory Cards" },
    new Category { Id = 69, Name = "Monitors" },
    new Category { Id = 70, Name = "RAM" },
    new Category { Id = 71, Name = "Computer Accessories" }
  };

  var GroupedData = new List<Category>();

  foreach(var category in categories)
  {
    if(category.Id == 0)
    {
      GroupedData.Add(category);
    }
    else
    {
      GroupedData.Last().Subcateogries.Add(category);
    }
  }

  return View(GroupedData);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<Category>

<h2>Categories</h2>

<ul>
  @foreach (var topCategory in Model)
  {
    <li>@topCategory.Name
      <ul>
        @foreach (var subCategory in topCategory.Subcateogries)
        {
          <li>@subCategory.Name</li>
        }
      </ul>
    </li>    
  }
</ul>
```

This is made with the assumptions that the starting list, in this case **categories** is in the order that you want.  I also took a short cut by just reusing the original list items when I created the **GroupedData**.  It is also assumed that there will only ever be two levels.

The view can be refactored to take advantage of partial views and handle multiple levels but that was not part of the question.